# How to pass cookie in http request - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-http, flutterwebviewplugin

What I'm trying do is access the Instagram private api which requires user to be logged in before sending request to it, so to achieve that, I accessed the cookies or session id with the help of flutter_web_view and webview_cookie_manager (basically making the user logged in through webview and then get the cookie using cookie_manager package)

But how to pass that cookie in http request?

```
// accessing cookie or session id
 
  WebViewController webViewController = WebViewController()
    ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://www.instagram.com/'))
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..setNavigationDelegate(
      NavigationDelegate(
        onPageFinished: (value) async {
          final cookieManager = WebviewCookieManager();
          List<Cookie> gotCookies = await cookieManager.getCookies('https://www.instagram.com/');
          print(gotCookies); // recieved the cookies
        }
      )
    )
  ;

var response = await http.get(private_api_url}); // how to pass cookies in this request
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
var response = await http.get(private_api_url, headers: {'cookie': cookie});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! One question though, to keep the session alive, do I need to store the cookie in sharedPreferences? or would I need to relogin whenever I restart the app?

Comment: Or maybe you can use the WebviewCookieManager for this? (I didn't try.)